# Data from ajax is not passing to PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, session, file-upload

I have this `html` page with `ajax` function called `upload(name)` to send a data to a `PHP` file (upload-ad-image-inc.php) for a image upload process.

I have already tried passing data using `ajax` to the relevant `PHP` file (upload-ad-image-inc.php).

And I got the passed data using a `POST` and assign it to a variable and so far so good. Data is passed but it is kind of `missing after that.`

**This is my Ajax function:**

```
       function upload(name) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'includes/upload-ad-image-inc.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    data: {
                        file: name
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                });

            });
        }
```

this is my `upload-ad-image-inc.php`

```
 $ind = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'file');

 echo $ind; //it shows file name successfully

 $adId = $_SESSION['adid'];
 $userId = $_SESSION['userid'];

 //after this the value of $ind is missing, cannot apply to any of above. 
 //They show empty outputs

 $file = $_FILES[$ind];
 $fileName = $_FILES[$ind]['name'];
 $fileTempName = $_FILES[$ind]['tmp_name'];
 $fileSize = $_FILES[$ind]['size'];
 $fileError = $_FILES[$ind]['error'];
 $fileType = $_FILES[$ind]['type'];

 echo $fileName; //this is where my problem. It doesn't show file name
```

In this part I get the file `name` attributes value

```
 $ind = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'file');

 echo $ind; //it shows file name successfully
```

but in below i don't get anything but `empty` values

```
 $file = $_FILES[$ind];
 $fileName = $_FILES[$ind]['name'];
 $fileTempName = $_FILES[$ind]['tmp_name'];
 $fileSize = $_FILES[$ind]['size'];
 $fileError = $_FILES[$ind]['error'];
 $fileType = $_FILES[$ind]['type'];

 echo $fileName; //this is where my problem. It doesn't show file name
```

This is my `HTML'

```
        <div class="image-uplod">
            <label class="custom-file image-uplod">
                <input style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="readURL(this, 'blah1', 'file1');" id="file1" name="file1" class=" btn btn-primary">
                <button style="display: none;" type="submit" name="submitUpload" class="custom-file-control btn btn-primary"><i class = 'fa fa-save'></i> Save</button>
            </label>


            <label class="custom-file image-uplod">
                <input style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="readURL(this, 'blah2', 'file2');" id="file2" name="file2" class=" btn btn-primary">
                <button style="display: none;" type="submit" name="submitUpload" class="custom-file-control btn btn-primary"><i class = 'fa fa-save'></i> Save</button>
            </label>


            <label class="custom-file image-uplod">
                <input style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="readURL(this, 'blah3', 'file3');" id="file3" name="file3" class=" btn btn-primary">
                <button style="display: none;" type="submit" name="submitUpload" class="custom-file-control btn btn-primary"><i class = 'fa fa-save'></i> Save</button>
            </label>


            <label class="custom-file image-uplod">
                <input style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="readURL(this, 'blah4', 'file4');" id="file4" name="file4" class=" btn btn-primary">
                <button style="display: none;" type="submit" name="submitUpload" class="custom-file-control btn btn-primary"><i class = 'fa fa-save'></i> Save</button>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you please share your HTML code?

Comment: @ranjitredekar: yes sure... I will update the question

Comment: @ranjitredekar done :) You can see it now

Comment: refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php